# Remove older geoxml3 layers when refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geoxml3

I have a google map on my web page, and uses geoxml3 to parse the layers (with many placemarks).

There is a timer that will trigger a jquery every 10 seconds to pull the new .kml file. However I want to remove the old layer, before parsing the new layer.

**Question:** What is the right way of removing/destroying?

I know there is a `geoXml.hideDocument();`, but that only hides the layer, it does not remove/destroy the layer right? (below is the hideDocument() implementation)

**refreshMap()** - hide previous layer and show new layer

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: "",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        if (data['success'] == 1) {
            if (geoXml) 
                geoXml.hideDocument();
            var src = data['kml'];
            geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                suppressInfoWindows: false,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
                infoWindow: infowindow,
                zoom : false
            });
            geoXml.parse(src);
            geoXml.showDocument();
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Even though this works, but my worry is that if it keeps pulling data every 10 seconds, if the page is opened for 1 hour, will it cause any lag? Reason being that the overlays are not actually destroyed/removed, they are still on memory, just that we lose the reference to it (because now reference point to the new layer).

**Update**

I found some information online, seems like I don't have to worry about this implementation.

> "Since Javascript is garbage collected, you don't need to delete
>   objects themselves - they will be removed when there is no way to
>   refer to them anymore."

Answer (score 0):

I have a [test case](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_update.html?lat=37.430783&lng=-122.085125&zoom=10&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/dynamicmarkerkml.php)
that effectively does this:

```
filename="http://www.geocodezip.com/dynamicmarkerkml.php";
geoXml.parse(filename);
setInterval("geoXml.hideDocument();geoXml.parse(filename)", 5000);
```

Doesn't leak memory that I can see and I have had it running for days (at one point, not recently).