# How to completely remove parsed geoXml from map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geoxml3, google-maps-drawing

how to remove drawn kml shape from map which is parsed by geoXml3 so that we can parse and draw a newone.
I am only seeing method of hideDocument and showDocument on geoXml but it doesn't completely remove.

```js
let filename = "http://localhost:5002/Nevada-2.kml";
let myLocation = { lat: 36.737061, lng: -119.7912549 };

function initialize() {
    let lat = 43.502745;
    let lng = -116.240845;
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    let zoom = 12;

    let myOptions = {
        zoom,
        center: myLatLng,
    };

    // create the map
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    let geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
    });
    geoXml.parse(filename);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(geoXml, "parsed", function () {
        let exist = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < geoXml.docs[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
            let placemark = geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[i];
            if (placemark.polygon) {
                if (
                    google.maps.geometry?.poly.containsLocation(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation),
                        placemark.polygon
                    )
                ) {
                    exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (exist) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: myLocation,
            });
            console.log("EXIST");
        } else {
            console.log("Doesn't Exist");
            console.log("geoXml: ", geoXml);
        }
    });
}
```

remove drawn kml shape from map which is parsed by geoXml3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326855/remove-older-geoxml3-layers-when-refresh

Comment: this doesn't solve.
after applying this code:
     geoXml.hideDocument();
                        geoXml.docs = [];
                        geoXml.parse("");
                        delete geoXml;

this command still shows that xml
geoXml.showDocument();

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to completely remove the `geoXml` object.

If you want to do that remove the `let` from its declaration then use `delete geoXml;` to delete it.

If you want to make it so `geoXml.showDocument()` doesn't display the loaded polygon (or markers or polylines), call `geoXml.hideDocument()` (to hide all the objects associated with that KML), then use `geoXml.docs.splice(0);` to remove that document's saved data.

change the posted code to this (will remove that data when `exist` is `false`):

```
  if (exist) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: myLocation,
    });
    console.log("EXIST");
  } else {
    console.log("Doesn't Exist");
    console.log("geoXml: ", geoXml);
    geoXml.hideDocument();
    geoXml.docs.splice(0);
    console.log("geoXml: ", geoXml);
    geoXml.showDocument();  // has no effect
  }
```

**working code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var geoXml;
let myLocation = {
  lat: 36.737061,
  lng: -119.7912549
};

function initialize() {
  let lat = 43.502745;
  let lng = -116.240845;
  myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  let zoom = 12;

  let myOptions = {
    zoom,
    center: myLatLng,
  };

  // create the map
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLocation,
    map: map
  });
  geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
  });

  geoXml.parseKmlString(kml_string, geoXml.docs[0]);
  // google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(geoXml, "parsed", function() { // parseKmlString is sychronous, no need to wait for event
  let exist = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < geoXml.docs[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
    let placemark = geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[i];
    if (placemark.polygon) {
      if (
        google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(
          new google.maps.LatLng(myLocation),
          placemark.polygon
        )
      ) {
        exist = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (exist) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: myLocation,
    });
    console.log("EXIST");
  } else {
    console.log("Doesn't Exist");
    console.log("geoXml: ", geoXml);
    geoXml.hideDocument();
    geoXml.docs.splice(0);
    console.log("geoXml: ", geoXml);
    geoXml.showDocument();
  }
  // });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var kml_string =
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><name>Untitled Project</name><Style id="polystyle"><LineStyle><color>ffd27619</color><width>3</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>40d27619</color></PolyStyle></Style><Placemark id="0EFB380192295F306ADE"><name>Nevada</name><styleUrl>#polystyle</styleUrl><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-119.9458168217553,42.09815848435698,1743.184968098506 -120.0136280431517,39.03898130098839,2759.571314474606 -114.6631133100423,35.02872903370762,148.2287681444774 -114.5754736462533,35.17759811926493,79.29195844202908 -114.7826439443366,36.09795001682222,504.6518724848692 -114.3826515827073,36.16850980887606,437.3265696852947 -114.2618037412561,35.94731934456748,1150.628738692156 -114.1585582237959,36.05914932215794,850.8799007465507 -114.0253602522288,36.21632653587633,722.0045967883513 -114.0424536177013,42.04153913557552,1577.542008078014 -119.9458168217553,42.09815848435698,1743.184968098506</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark></Document></kml>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Import KML</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>

</html>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
```